# Rounded google maps custom marker android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, picasso, android-glide

I want to add a custom marker that looks like this: [image: Markers that have image inside them and are rounded]

How can I achieve this? I am using Glide and Picasso libraries.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `MarkerOptions`

```
MarkerOptions markerOptionsObj = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.Your_Icon));
```

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Picasso to download/load the pictures, then you can  use a [Transformation](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Transformation.html) to intercept the bitmap and make it rounded. The callback gives you the bitmap to transform. You can easily use a  `BitmapShader` with the [TileMode.CLAMP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.TileMode.html) to make it round

Comment: thank you good sir. Can you give me an example how can I Do that?

Comment: to round the picture?

Comment: Yes, I made the PicassoMarker class, should I do that onBitmapLoaded?

Comment: I would use a `Transformation`. To make it round you can take inspiration from [here](http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/). Instead of drawing a rounded rect, you have to draw a circle

Comment: Ok, Iv done that. Now, how can i center image in that circle?

Answer (score 1):

To add a custom marker in your map you can use this line of code:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(yourBitmap);
```